# Check if a Type derives from a Interface with more than one Generic Argument

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a question about loading types with reflection. I am attempting to filter the list of types in an Assembly by those which implement an interface with two generic parameters. I don't intend to explicitly tell which types are those generic parameters since I want all classes that implement the interface but whenever I attempt to use `typeof(IExample<>)` it gets marked as an error. However, it's possible to do it with an interface that only has one generic parameter.
I would really appreciate some help with this! Thanks in advance :)

```
public interface IExample<T, E>
{
}
```

This is how my interface would looks like.
And then I currently have to classes that implement it.

```
public class C 
{
}

public class A : IExample<string, C>
{
}

Public class B : IExample<XMLDocument, C>
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't to far off from what I could examine from your question. In order to get the correct generic type, without any generic arguments you need to call `typeof(IExample<,>)`, note that there is a comma!

---

For the other part of your question on how to get those types you can do something like the following:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesWithGenericArguments(Assembly assembly, Type implementingInterface)
{
    var types = assembly.GetTypes();

    // Loop over all Types in the assembly
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        // Skipping all Types which aren't classes
        if (!type.IsClass)
            continue;

        var implementedInterfaces = type.GetInterfaces();

        // Loop over all interfaces the type implements
        foreach (var implementedInterface in implementedInterfaces)
        {
            // Return the type if it one of its interfaces are matching the implementingInterface
            if (implementedInterface.IsGenericType && implementedInterface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == implementingInterface)
            {
                yield return type;
                // You can leave the loop, since you don't need to check the other
                // interfaces, since you already found the one you were searching for.
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which could be used like that:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var item in GetTypesWithGenericArguments(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), typeof(IExample<,>)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }

    // This would print to the Console:
    // A
    // B
}
```